# Project Folder already exists and is not empty. in Apache NetBeans 12.1

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

After using Apache Netbeans 12.1 for some days, today (without touching the installation folders) I tried to create a new project but I got the error message

> "Project Folder already exists and is not empty"

NetBeans creates instead a `"default folder"`, that doesn't open automatically in which you cannot create any package or class.

---

I used to save my projects in a different folder in my hard disk instead of the default one (the one that NetBeans creates inside "Documents") but I've never got any kind of problem.

---

I deleted all my folders in which I used to have Java projects and i re-installed NetBeans, Java and JDK many and many times (trying different methods like uninstalling from control panel, from uninstall.exe, etc...) but I was not able to solve it.

I started to think that may be a compatibility issue with NetBeans and JDK because I'm not able to create any package or class and also because after the reinstallation I noticed that the NetBeans User Interface changed, like it was a new version of the software (may be not compatible with my JDK yet?).

---

I'm currently using Windows 10. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I apparently solved deleting %appdata% files.

Answer (score 0):

That means the default project destination folder that NetBeans picking up for you (or you manually) is not empty and has some files inside it. Open the Explorer and create a new folder inside the same directory and select that while creating a Project.

Comment: I tried this many times but didn't work. I solved deleting %appdata% files, maybe there were some projects files that gave me problems. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @14PaoloT You should put it as an official answer, this solved my problem